# Haskell Persistent How to add a field to an existing table of a sql database

Tags: sql, haskell, persistent

Given the following Persistent database definition:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Mount
   name String
   UniqueName name
   desc String
  deriving Show

FaceSlope
  slope Double
  mountId MountId
  MountIdForFaceSlope mountId
 deriving Show

FaceDimensions
  zTop Double
  zBtm Double
  zHeight Double default=5.0
  leftx Double
  lefty Double
  rightx Double
  righty Double
  mountId MountId
  MountIdForFaceDimensions mountId
 deriving Show

CurrentMount
  mountId MountId
 deriving Show
|]
```

I need to add `zHeight` to the `FaceDimensions` table. I gave it a default value for any existing rows already in the db.

When I `runMigration migrateAll` I get the following error.

> PersistMarshalError "field zHeight: Expected Double, received:
>   PersistText \"z_height\""

To get this to work, I had to manually add the field to the sqlite database.
Is there a way I could have done this directly through Persistent?

Comment: does it work without the default=5.0 bit?

Comment: The error generally means that you have a column that already exists that has the wrong value. Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE face_dimensions;`?

Comment: I will reproduce the error on another table.

Answer (score 0):

Alec:

No it did not work without the default. The problem was in adding a new field, where there are existing rows which do not contain any value for the new field. That is why I tried the default, to see if the pre-existing rows would get the default value when the new field(column) was inserted. I reproduced a similar error here.

```
share
 [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
  WristDimensions
   name String
   UniqueWristDimensionName name
   desc String
   squaredOffRiserHeight Double 
   radius Double 
   power Double  
  deriving Show
  |]
```

Now I add in some data to populate a row so there is pre-existing data in the table. Then trying adding a new field (newField Double).

```
  share 
   [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
   WristDimensions
   name String
   UniqueWristDimensionName name
   desc String
   squaredOffRiserHeight Double 
   radius Double 
   power Double  
   newField Double
   deriving Show
  |]
```

Now when I run migration:
Giving the following error.

```
Migrating: CREATE TEMP TABLE 
"wrist_dimensions_backup"("id" INTEGER    PRIMARY KEY,"name" 
 VARCHAR NOT NULL,"desc" VARCHAR NOT  NULL,
 "squared_off_riser_height" REAL NOT NULL,
 "radius" REAL NOT NULL,"power" REAL NOT NULL,"new_field" REAL NOT    
 NULL,CONSTRAINT "unique_wrist_dimension_name" UNIQUE ("name"))
 Migrating: INSERT INTO "wrist_dimensions_backup"   
 ("id","name","desc","squared_off_riser_height","radius","power") SELECT 
 "id","name","desc","squared_off_riser_height","radius","power" FROM  
 "wrist_dimensions"
  ChampCad-exe: SQLite3 returned ErrorConstraint while attempting to perform step.
```

Maybe instead of: runMigration migrateAll there is a way of updating that gets around this constraint.